# Struts2, JSP, Test String for null and Empty in iteration

Tags: java, string, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2

I am using Struts2. And having trouble in test a String for null or empty. The String is in a loop.

What I have done so far is

in Action class I have a `List<User>`. `User` have `id` and `name` fields and have getters and setters...

in JSP i am doing like

```
<s:iterator value="userList" var="user" status="userStatus">
    <s:if test"%{user.name != null && user.name != ''}">
       ${user.name}
       <!-- Do some thing... -->
    </s:if>
</s:iterator>
```

Problem is that Its not working :(, I cannot see the names and they are visible if I remove the `<s:if>` block.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try with this

```
<s:if test="%{#user.name != null && #user.name != ''}">
   <s:property value="#user.name"/>
   <!-- Do some thing... -->
</s:if>
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I am also confused in checking string in Java works in `equals()`, is it same as `!=` or `==` in Struts tag in JSP.